# How to upload large files in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upload, large-file-upload

How to upload large files in ASP.Net MVC 4

I have code like this in the controller:

> Request.Files.Get("img").SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ImgSong/" + +Out.Id + ".jpg"));

It only allows uploading a small file, while the file I want to upload would 
 range from 10Mb to 100Mb.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change you web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The default value is 4096kb. You need to change this value to 10240 for 10mb uploading.

Comment: I have to do what you instruct but still an error, here is the picture![enter image description here][1]

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/y6xVK.png

Comment: This error means you have <security> tag on web.config but don't have configsections. Can you try only with my code if not run than try only @Kamlesh's code.By the way you have already <system.web> section. You need to write httpruntime thing only.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `web.config` as per size of file.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="10240" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10240" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
</system.web>
```