# How to upload large files in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to upload large files (up to 1 GB) in `ASP.NET MVC5` , I have tried many solutions from here.

[How to upload large files in ASP.Net MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526106/how-to-upload-large-files-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

[How to upload large files using MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287706/how-to-upload-large-files-using-mvc-4)

But any changes in web.config causes the following error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
> accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
> invalid.

I can't add anything in web.config.

[image: web.config error]

Comment: error is saying you already have httpruntime in the web.config.remove the duplicate entry

Comment: thanks @user9405863 this is right! can you please write your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Error you are getting is about duplicate entry of `HttpRuntime` in web.config. Remove the duplicate entry. you should be good